# How do I archive or copy the entire Inbox using Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

What steps do I need to take to archive or make a copy of my entire Inbox (Ubuntu 12.04)? I don't want a few messages. I want to copy the whole Inbox tree.

Basically, I don't care if I use the Archive function or not. I just want to put under a different folder 2012's email, and hopefully compress and archive, too.

Comment: Which OS on you are?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 is my platform.

Comment: I have posted an answer regarding this, did that helped? Let me know if I could help you further.

Comment: did you find a way to actually "compress" (not compact) the archived emails database/files/folder in a way that is still usable by thunderbird?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the comment you provided under the other answer I assumed you have Ubuntu. Also you have mentioned that

> **Basically, I don't care if I use the Archive function or not. I just want to put under a different folder 2012's email, and hopefully compress and archive, too.**

As I don't have Ubuntu for testing this but I got [How do I back up Thunderbird emails?](https://askubuntu.com/q/114015/24391) on [Ask Ubuntu SE netwotrk](http://askubuntu.com) and provided solution is

> Go to your home folder & press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>h</kbd>  to view hidden folders
>
> copy & backup "**.thunderbird**" folder

[image]

> Inside .thunderbird you should see a bunch of files and folders named
> Cache, Mail, ImapMail etc
>
> If not, then you have relocated your profile folder.
>
> Your actual profile folder is defined in a file named 'profiles.ini'
>
> Open it with a text viewer/editor and you will see something like
> this:

```
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1

[Profile0]
Name=Default User
IsRelative=0
Path=/media/diskF/ThunderbirdMail/5mu9j6vu.default
Default=1
```

The 'Path' is the real folder to backup.

Answer (score 0):

> How to Automatically Archive Messages in Thunderbird:
>   [How to get Thunderbird to archive messages automatically](https://superuser.com/questions/214205/how-to-get-thunderbird-to-archive-messages-automatically?rq=1)

Here's a post from the Mozilla Thunderbird support team that explains how to archive your inbox (en-masse).

The post recommends that you do not exceed 2000 e-mails, but in the event that you exceed this recommendation, simply subdivide your task into 2-3 jobs.

1. To archive 1..M messages, select the desired messages then,
2. Click the 'Archive' button, or 'A' on the keyboard
3. Messages will be sent to your configured archive destination.

See the post for information on how to configure your archive destination.

If you're using IMAP, you don't need to worry about old messages consuming additional hard drive space (as opposed to POP3).

https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/archived-messages

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I visited these. It does not work for me on Ubuntu 12.04. I click on Inbox, and Archive is disabled.